# Do I need to ground the thermal pad on the MAX8808?

Tags: battery-charging, schematics, fault

I have designed the [MAX8808](https://www.analog.com/en/products/max8808x.html) LiPo charger IC into one of my designs. It doesn't seem to be working, in the sense that no current is flowing into the LiPo cell, despite all of the DC conditions suggesting that it should.

The only potential problem I can see with my design is that I forgot to connect the exposed thermal pad to Gnd. The chip does have a Gnd pin, which I have connected to Gnd.

It is likely that this chip isn't working because the pad isn't connected to Gnd? (If the answer is yes, I'm going to have to take the chip off and hand-drill a via under it).

Voltages measured at the pins:

1. IN: 5.2v
2. VL: 3.0v
3. GND
4. ISet: 0.02v
5. nCHG: pulls down to 0.25 when charge is enabled. 2.25v when not - enabled.
6. nEn: pulled down to 0.0v when enabled, 3.3v when not enabled.
7. nACOK: pulled down to 0.19v when USB power connected. 3.3v otherwise.
8. BATT: 3.42v

Comment: Make some measurements, maybe you have an open connection. Check the voltage across the current set resistor is close to nominal 1.4V, for example. And that the voltage across the VL bypass cap is close to 3V. Of course you should connect the paddle, but there may be something else wrong.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I have checked all of the connections, and everything looks correct. VL cap is exactly 3.00v.

Comment: Can you connect ground temporarily to the EP to see what happens. The datsheet says DO IT as Andy notes.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Yep. Added it, and it seems to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Do I need to ground the thermal pad on the MAX8808?*

Read the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX8808X-MAX8808Z.pdf) page 5: -

[image]

> *It is likely that this chip isn't working because the pad isn't
> connected to Gnd?*

Impossible to say because the data sheet does not cover wrong/incorrect wiring scenarios.

Comment: I did read that. But I wasn't sure if it meant that the chip simply wouldn't work without it. That's the only mention.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet. It would appear the datasheet advises for maximum power Chip dissipation, the ground pad EP should be connected to your PCB ground plane. This is very common with such devices and the default thing to do is to connect the EP pad to your ground plane(s) using a couple of vias etc. Having said that, it does not suggest this connection is crucial for the correct function of the device (more of a maximum power dissipation issue). It sounds more probable there is something else preventing the correct function as expected, maybe a floating pin somwhere or some other reason ...

Comment: @citizen please don't misquote the data sheet. It unambiguously states that you should "Connect GND to the exposed paddle directly under the IC". This is a separate sentence to the one you are referring to AND, the only meaning can be is that you need a pad for the exposed paddle. Of course you might get away without it but, that is not what the data sheet says. Regarding your 2nd comment. please place this directly under the question because it does not apply to my answer.

Comment: I managed to add a wire under the chip (not easy) and now it charges! Many thanks.